# Sobolev $H^1$ dual space definition

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm kinda confused on the definition of a dual space of $H^1(U)$. In evans it states the $f\in H^{-1}(U)$ if $f$ is a bounded linear functional. Does that mean $f$ takes in functions $u\in H^1(U)$ and return a some real number (as thats what a functional is). So if $f = f_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n f^i_{x_1}$ for $f_i \in L^2$ how do we know $f\in H^{-1}(U)$? Apologies for the trivial question, I don't have a formal understanding of sobolev space as it was not really covered in my course but I'm trying to understand weak solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You might define a $H^{-1}$ functional just by using Green's formula. For instance, for any fixed $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ you have $$
f_{x_1}^i(u)=-\int_\Omega f^i(x)u_{x_1}(x)dx+\int_{\partial\Omega}f^i(x)u(x)n_1(x)dx=-\int_\Omega f^i(x)u_{x_1}(x)dx,
$$
where in the last equality we have used the fact that $H^{-1}$ is defined as the dual of $H_0^1$ and not of $H^1$ as you stated on your question. This difference is important since it allows you to cancel the term on the boundary $\partial\Omega$. On the other hand, notice that if $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$, then we have  $H^{1}_0=H^1$, so in this case there is no difference.

**Edit:** Just to be clear, for the function $f\in L^2$ which does not involve any derivative, you may just identify it with a functional in $H^{1-}$ as $$
f(u)=\int_\Omega f(x)u(x)dx.
$$
Therefore, adding up all the terms $f,f_{x_1}^1,...,f_{x_1}^n$, by denoting $F=f+\sum_{i=1}^nf_{x_1}^i$ we have $$
F(u)=\int_\Omega f(x)u(x)dx-\sum_{i=1}^n\int_\Omega f^i(x)u_{x_1}(x)dx \quad \hbox{for all }\, u\in H_0^1(\Omega).
$$

Comment: It seem that in their f it also involves derivatives, you may need to explain that too.

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen the derivatives. Thank you!